# Combine Two Tables in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two Tables in a SQL 2008 database that I need to merge two column's when I run the query.

**Table1** I need `Emply_ID`, `Emply_Name`, `Emply_HomeDept`, `Emply_Shift`

**Table2** I need `Emply_ID`, `Emply_OtherDept`, `Emply_AltShift`.

What I'd to be able to do is produce a single row, combining `HomeDept` and `OtherDept` together and `Shift` and `AltShift` together. So I would end up with

```
00124|John Doe|Loading,Packing,Shipping|Shift1,Shift2,Shift3
```

Comment: and whats the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should meet your expectations:

```
SELECT t.EmplyId, 
       t.Emply_name, 
       CONCAT(t.Emply_HomeDept, ',' , x.otherDept) AS FullDept,
       CONCAT(t.Emply_Shift, ',' , x.AltShift) AS FullShift,
FROM
    Table1 t
    LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT t2.EmplyId,
           (SELECT t3.OtherDept + ',' AS [text()] 
            FROM table2 t3
            WHERE t3.EmplyId = t2.EmplyId
            FOR XML PATH ('')
           ) AS otherDept,
           (SELECT t4.AltShift + ',' AS [text()] 
            FROM table2 t4
            WHERE t4.EmplyId = t2.EmplyId
            FOR XML PATH ('')
           ) AS AltShift           
    FROM
        Table2 t2 ) x
    ON t.Emply_Id = x.EmplyId
```